# How to setup signet with bitcoin core locally

Tags: bitcoin-core, signet

I am trying to run a signet network locally using bitcoin core. I have downloaded bitcoin core and upon installation, it seems I have to go through the Initial Block Download process.

I am only interested in running the signet network. Please how can I skip the IBD process since I am not interested in mainnet transactions?

Answer (score 1):

If you run bitcoind with the `-signet` flag you will not do IBD for mainnet, you will just do IBD for signet. The signet IBD will not take long to complete.